# moving to next page after animated splash screen

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

i am new to  ionic4/angular4. i have created a nice animated splash screen in a page but after the splash screen animation is over at some point of time i need to move forward to another page.i have provided my config details and i didn't installed cordova splash plugin.i thought it is not needed.please help me by providing code snippets.i am stuck for two days.

```js
export class HomePage {
splash= true;
  constructor() {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => 
    {
      this.splash = false;
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

```css
ion-content {
 --background: #FFBF00;
}

.tree {
 left: 0;
 right: 5%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

.tree>div {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #FFBF00;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-animation-name: hello;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-name: hello;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes hello {
 0% {
  height: 100%;
 }
 100% {
  height: 0%;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hello {
 0% {
  height: 100%;
 }
 100% {
  height: 0%;
 }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="tree" text-center [style.display]="splash ? 'block': 'none'">
    <div></div>
    <img src="assets/logo.svg">
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Comment: This really depends on how you navigate in your app - regardless of the splash screen. Do you use a router? Then you can put this in your timeout: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/nextpage')`.

Comment: use angular `Router` for Navigation .

Comment: after certain amount of time i need to switch. how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

add below line your `config.xml` file

```
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

and use `modalController` for splashScreen show like,

```
ionViewDidEnter() {

  this.splashScreen.hide();

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }, 4000);

}
```