# Ionic app got stuck on white screen after splash screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen

I have developed one ionic application, which get stucks after splash screen. App continuously shows white screen.

My code from confid file is as below

```
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Chrome/41.0.2228.0" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Typically in the app.component.ts class constructor:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
```

Please help me

Comment: refer this Link: -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004128/moving-to-next-page-after-animated-splash-screen/57006099#57006099

Comment: something throwing an error and you're not catching it that's why it happens.

Comment: you are build using dev or prod?

Comment: @ArpitPandey Is their any way to find out error log?

Comment: @Velu Dhanesh We tried for both dev and prod build

Answer (score 0):

try to change this to

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="75000" />
```

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: Bcz splash screen is being delayed

Comment: So how does that fix this?

Comment: You have to apply lasy loading it will fix —prod flag run it using that

Comment: The OP already has `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />`. What is your argument for using 75000 instead?

Comment: its delaynig other than that run `ionic android run --prod --release`

Comment: @orbit In the case of ionic android run --prod --release apk is in not working